# Grouped operation on all groups relative to "baseline" group, with multiple observations

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Starting with data containing multiple observations for each group, like this:

```
set.seed(1)
my.df <- data.frame(
  timepoint = rep(c(0, 1, 2), each= 3),
  counts = round(rnorm(9, 50, 10), 0)
)
> my.df
  timepoint counts
1         0     44
2         0     52
3         0     42
4         1     66
5         1     53
6         1     42
7         2     55
8         2     57
9         2     56
```

To perform a summary calculation at each `timepoint` relative to `timepoint == 0`, for each group I need to pass a vector of counts for `timepoint == 0` and a vector of counts for the group (e.g. `timepoint == 0`) to an arbitrary function, e.g.

```
NonsenseFunction <- function(x, y){
  (mean(x) - mean(y)) / (1 - mean(y))
}
```

I can get the required output from this table, either with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
my.df %>%
  group_by(timepoint) %>%
  mutate(rep = paste0("r", 1:n())) %>%
  left_join(x = ., y = filter(., timepoint == 0), by = "rep") %>%
  group_by(timepoint.x) %>%
  summarise(result = NonsenseFunction(counts.x, counts.y))
```

or `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
my.dt <- data.table(my.df)
my.dt[, rep := paste0("r", 1:length(counts)), by = timepoint]
merge(my.dt, my.dt[timepoint == 0], by = "rep", all = TRUE)[
  , NonsenseFunction(counts.x, counts.y), by = timepoint.x]
```

This only works if the number of observations between groups is the same. Anyway, the observations aren't matched, so using the temporary `rep` variable seems hacky.

For a more general case, where I need to pass vectors of the baseline values and the group's values to an arbitrary (more complicated) function, is there an idiomatic `data.table` or `dplyr` way of doing so with a grouped operation for all groups?

Comment: Please use `set.seed()` when creating data frames with such functions as `rnorm` so we all get the same results

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that. Edited.

Comment: This may be obvious but `my.df[, f(counts, my.df[timepoint==0, counts]), by=timepoint]`, where `f` is your function. By the way, I think it's your last chunk of code that's leading to confusion (that you want it for this particular function and not a more general case).

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the comment, I have edited the question. Is it clearer now? Your `data.table` suggestion is what I was looking for. It *is* pretty obvious now that you've pointed it out. Want to make it answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the straightforward data.table approach:

```
my.dt[, f(counts, my.dt[timepoint==0, counts]), by=timepoint]
```

This probably grabs `my.dt[timepoint==0, counts]` again and again, for each group. You could instead save that value ahead of time:

```
v = my.dt[timepoint==0, counts]
my.dt[, f(counts, v), by=timepoint]
```

... or if you don't want to add `v` to the environment, maybe

```
with(list(v = my.dt[timepoint==0, counts]), 
  my.dt[, f(counts, v), by=timepoint]
)
```

Comment: So obvious, I'm embarrassed I missed it. I'm going to leave the question open for a `dplyr` answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the second argument to use the vector from your group of interest as a constant.

```
my.df %>%
    group_by(timepoint) %>%
    mutate(response = NonsenseFunction(counts, my.df$counts[my.df$timepoint == 0]))
```

Or if you want to make it beforehand:

```
constant = = my.df$counts[my.df$timepoint == 0]
my.df %>%
    group_by(timepoint) %>%
    mutate(response = NonsenseFunction(counts, constant))
```

Comment: +1 I accepted the other answer because it was posted first, but this is the `dplyr` approach I asked for. I like the readable code you usually get with `dplyr`, but on this occassion I find the `data.table` approach easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
library(dplyr)
my.df %>% 
    mutate(new = mean(counts[timepoint == 0])) %>% 
    group_by(timepoint) %>% 
    summarise(result = NonsenseFunction(counts, new))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
#  timepoint    result
#      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1         0 0.0000000
#2         1 0.1398601
#3         2 0.2097902
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good for this dummy function, but for a more complicated calculation that uses several statistics (`mean()`, `var()`, `length()` ...) it's no more convenient than making a summary table, and each summary statistic would have to be passed to the function.

Comment: Yes but note that `mean(c(10, 8))` is 9 whereas `mean(c(9, 9))` is also 9

Comment: I thought your goal was to be able to apply your function to non-equal groups without having to do summary table. This code does that. I am not sure what you are after

Comment: Basically, passing a vector of counts for the baseline (`timepoint == 0`) and for the group to an arbitrary function for each group.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried to make the question clearer.